# Authorize GitHub OAuth Flow with SwaggerUI

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, oauth-2.0, swagger-ui, swashbuckle

I've been setting up a WebApi using dotNet core 2.2 and I wanted to Authorize my users using GitHub's OAuth.

I looked up and setup my API to use `Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Swagger` for its Swagger docs and UI and used AspNetCore's own Authentication to setup OAuth. Everything works like a charm when signing in or out via my endpoints `auth/signin|out` however whenever I try to authorize my client via the SwaggerUI's Authorize button I get an error:

```
Exception: The oauth state was missing or invalid.
Exception: An error was encountered while handling the remote login.
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.RemoteAuthenticationHandler<TOptions>.HandleRequestAsync()
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles.StaticFileMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerUI.SwaggerUIMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Swagger.SwaggerMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext, ISwaggerProvider swaggerProvider)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
```

The following are some of the code I use to setup stuff around the API:

```
// Setting up Authentication
services
.AddAuthentication(opt =>
{
    opt.DefaultScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    opt.DefaultChallengeScheme = "GitHub";
})
.AddCookie()
.AddGitHub("GitHub", opt =>
{
    opt.ClientId = GitHubSettings.ClientId;                             
    opt.ClientSecret = GitHubSettings.ClientSecret;     
    opt.CallbackPath = new PathString(GitHubSettings.CallbackPath);
    opt.SaveTokens = true;
});
```

```
// Setting up SwaggerDoc Generation
services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
{
    c.AddSecurityDefinition("GitHub", new OAuth2Scheme
    {
        Type = "oauth2",
        Flow = "accessCode",
        AuthorizationUrl = "https://github.com/login/oauth/authorize",
        TokenUrl = "https://github.com/login/oauth/access_token"
    });

    c.SwaggerDoc("v1", new Info
    {
        Version = "v1",
        Title = "NetCore Playground API",
        Description = "API para testes com .NET Core 2.2",
        Contact = new Contact { Name = "HocusPocus", Url = @"https://google.com", Email = "not.my.email@gmail.com" }   
    });
});
```

```
// Using SwaggerUI
app.UseSwagger();
app.UseSwaggerUI(opt =>
{
    opt.DisplayRequestDuration();
    opt.RoutePrefix = string.Empty;
    opt.SwaggerEndpoint("swagger/v1/swagger.json", "Playground API V1");
    opt.OAuth2RedirectUrl("https://localhost:5001/auth/callback");
    opt.OAuthClientId(GitHubSettings.ClientId);
    opt.OAuthClientSecret(GitHubSettings.ClientSecret);
    opt.OAuthAppName("dotNet Core Playground");
});
app.UseAuthentication();
```

This is for an OpenSource learning project so the source is available on GitHub: 
 https://github.com/rodolphocastro/ARDC.NetCore.Playground/tree/feature/stackoverflow-57086626/src/ARDC.NetCore.Playground

Edit: I've made some changes to the code based on https://www.jerriepelser.com/blog/authenticate-oauth-aspnet-core-2/ and still no success with SwaggerUI's Authorize button.

Comment: If anyone's interested, created an issue at Swashbuckle's GitHub regarding this: https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore/issues/1199

Answer (score 0):

Change the port number of OAuth2RedirectUrl -(application port number)

```
// Using SwaggerUI
app.UseSwagger();
app.UseSwaggerUI(opt =>
{
    opt.DisplayRequestDuration();
    opt.RoutePrefix = string.Empty;
    opt.SwaggerEndpoint("swagger/v1/swagger.json", "Playground API V1");
    opt.OAuth2RedirectUrl("https://localhost:5001/auth/callback");
    opt.OAuthClientId(GitHubSettings.ClientId);
    opt.OAuthClientSecret(GitHubSettings.ClientSecret);
    opt.OAuthAppName("dotNet Core Playground");
});
app.UseAuthentication();
```

Comment: Unfortunately changing from port 5001 to 5000 (and from https to http) in both the api and my oauth app in GitHub gives me an URI_REDIRECT_ERROR due to HttpsRedirect and HSTS. If I remove HSTS and HttpsRedirect I still get the same error on port 5000